# css - Abolute position of div inside div

Tags: css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="avatar" style="border:1px dotted gray;height:100px;width:100px;float:left;text-align:center;">
    <img id="imgLogo" src="images/your-logo-here.png" style="width:auto;height:auto; max-height:100%; max-width:100%;" />
    <div class="form-inline" style="padding-top:5px;text-align:left;">
        <button type="button" class="btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>
            <input id="btnLogo" type="file" class="upload">
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn-primary"> <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

The problem appears when the image is smaller then the buttons div goes up and I need that div to always stay on that position.

[image]

> Any clue?

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.fake-sample-img {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.buttons {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="fake-sample-img"></div>
  
  <div class="buttons">
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Put a `position: relative` on your parent element. Then position: absolute with bottom: value on your child.

Comment: I need to keep the max-width; and min-width, also I want to keep the image proportional to the area. Already try the code but not working.

Comment: @VAAA you don't need to copy all the style I provided. I'm just giving you an example of my answer. This is the right way to do it. And, look for staypuffman answer. We have the same answer :) Using relative and absolute technique.

Comment: I already try with bottom: -30px and that works nice. Appreciate it

Comment: Do you know how can I center vertically the image?

Comment: @VAAA Glad I helped ;) see you around next time

Comment: @VAAA you can try to put text-align: center on your parent or margin: 0 auto on your image.

Comment: Lara is it possible to get your info might need help for a project. Thanks

Comment: Sure. I love helping others. Here's my email. larabelleluna@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks just sent you a message. Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is that you need to make your container element positioned relatively while the image is positioned absolutely at the top of the container and the buttons are positioned absolutely at the bottom of that container.

At a high level, that looks like:

```
.avatar {
  position: relative;
}

#imgLogo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.form-inline {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```